# Slow performance on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, nightmare

I am currently learning how to use *NightmareJS*. I found the performance is so slow while I was running the code below. It took up to 30 seconds to get the output. Did I do anything wrong?

Moreover, I have tried to use `wait()` with a selector but that does not help so much.

I am not sure whether this is related to my Internet connection, however, open the same site using Google Chrome and perform the same task is faster than using *Nightmare*.

**Soruce Code**

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');

var after;
var before = Date.now();

new Nightmare({
    loadImages: false
  }).goto('https://www.wikipedia.org/')
  .type('#searchInput', process.argv[2])
  .click('input[name="go"]')
  .wait()
  .url(function(url) {
    after = Date.now();
    console.log('>>> [' + (after - before) / 1000.0 + 's] ' + url);
  })
  .run(function(err, nightmare) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
```

**Output**

```
node n02_extract_wiki_link.js "node.js"
>>> [31.227s] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js
```

My current environment is listed below.

```
Mac OS X 10.10.4
node v0.12.5
PhantomJS 2.0.0
nightmare@1.8.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:
https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/126#issuecomment-75944613

> It's the socket connection between the phantomjs module and it's dependency, shoe.
>
> You can manually edit shoe yourself. Go into node_modules/phantom/shoe/index.js and change line 8 to read
>
> ```
> var server = sockjs.createServer({
>         heartbeat_delay : 200
> });
> ```